# React date time picker compatible with mongo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am using Reactstrap in my project and it currently only has 2 separate inputs (date and time). Does anyone know of one datetime picker that is compatible with MongoDB's format (`2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00`). Reactstrap doesnt have one and html's `datetime-local` type doesn't seem to work

Answer (score -1):

What is the output from Datetime picker?
Maybe you could write a formatter function to get your goal.